# Remove whitespace in string using for loop

Tags: r, whitespace, stringr

I learned about stringr library and tried to use it to remove whitespace from a string, but I don't understand why it would not remove it when I index a string from a vector.

`ex` is a vector with strings similar to `"  1950"`

```
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all(ex[1], fixed("  "), "")
[1] "  1950"
> str_replace_all("  1950", fixed("  "), "")
[1] "1950"
> str("  1950")
 chr "  1950"
> str(ex[1])
 chr "  1950"
```

I wanted to write a loop to remove the whitespaces, but I don't understand why `stringr` does not work when I use `ex[1]`

Following is `dput(ex)`

```
c("  1950", "  1951", "  1952", "  1953", "  1954", 
"  1955", "  1956", "  1957", "  1958", "  1959", "  1960", 
"  1961", "  1962", "  1963", "  1964", "  1965", "  1966", 
"  1967", "  1968", "  1969", "  1970", "  1971", "  1972", 
"  1973", "  1974", "  1975", "  1976", "  1977", "  1978", 
"  1979", "  1980", "  1981", "  1982", "  1983", "  1984", 
"  1985", "  1986", "  1987", "  1988", "  1989", "  1990", 
"  1991", "  1992", "  1993", "  1994", "  1995", "  1996", 
"  1997", "  1998", "  1999", "  2000", "  2001", "  2002", 
"  2003", "  2004", "  2005", "  2006", "  2007", "  2008", 
"  2009", "  2010", "  2011", "  2012", "  2013", "  2014", 
"  2015", "  2016", "  2017", "        ", "Provided by :   All China Marketing Resarch"
)
```

What library can I use in a for loop to remove whitespaces?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier with `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(ex)
```

---

The OP's issue is not reproducible with `str_extract`

```
stringr::str_replace_all(ex[1], fixed("  "), "")
#[1] "1950"
```

Comment: @song0089  Not able to reproduce the issue.  Can you try it on a fresh R session?

Comment: @song0089 In addition, stringr has a much more appropriate function than `str_replace_all`, `str_trim`, that also works just as well as `trimws`.

Comment: Hi, I think the reason I had the issue was because ex was subsetted from a data frame using '$'. But still it is a vector -- why would it cause the problem?

Comment: @song0089. It won't be an issue.  I would start on a fresh session with only stringr loaded to debug the issue.

Comment: @akrun I still have issues, I trimws does not work when I try to run a column from a data frame -- > class(ge)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(ge$Year)
[1] "character"
> trimws(ge$Year)

Comment: @song0089. It is strange that you have an issue.  Have you assigned the output back to the column i.e. `ge$Year <- trimws(ge$Year)` ?

Answer (score 2):

`str_trim` within `library(stringr)` would work

i.e

```
 trimmed = str_trim(your_string, which = c('left'))
```

For right trim, you could set it to `right` or for both sides, `both`. You also wouldn't need to loop in this case. A vector of strings can be passed directly to `str_trim`.